# Importtsv command does not work in Hbase1.0.1.1

Tags: hadoop, hbase, csv

I am trying to import a tsv file into my hbase table. I am using the following command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hbase-1.0.1.1/lib/hbase-it-1.0.1.1.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,a,b '-Dtable_name.separator=\t' table-name /path-to-input-file
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: importtsv
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Have added guava jar in Hadoop classpath. Below is my bashrc file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase-1.0.1.1

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar

export HBASE_CONF_DIR=$HBASE_HOME/conf
export HBASE_CLASS_PATH=$HBASE_CONF_DIR
export PATH=$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**PS: Hadoop version - 2.6.0, Hbase version-1.0.1.1**

Comment: Are you looking to run `bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv` ?

Comment: I want to import a tsv file data into a Hbase table. Am I referring the correct hbase jar?

Comment: I think you're using the wrong command.  Refer to the following : http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#importtsv

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Yes, I was using the wrong command.